# Mouse control (SendInput) during UAC prompt

Tags: windows, winapi, uac

I have a embedded touch interface that I am using in a windows 10 environment. I am using the SendInput function to translate the touch events to mouse events.

This does not appear to work when the UAC prompt is shown. Is it possible for a background application to control the mouse during the UAC prompt? Would it work if the touch translation was done in a service?
(needed so that users can perform upgrades by running an install package).

Comment: [By default, the UAC prompt is displayed on a secure desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-switch-to-the-secure-desktop-when-prompting-for-elevation). A UI can't be interacted with across desktop/session boundaries. So unless your app is associated with the same desktop that the UAC prompt runs on, then no.

Comment: If standard user could fake input on the UAC secure desktop, it wouldn't be very secure would it?

Comment: Sounds like a service running as Admin would not work either. Note sure I want to go down the path of writing a Windows driver. May just say that upgrades require the user to connect a mouse.

Comment: @Martin a service running as SYSTEM might have access. Look at `SetProcessWindowStation()` and `SetThreadDesktop()`. With enough rights and no prior UI, a desktop app might be able to do this, too. Not sure how hard it would be to find the secure desktop and gain access to it, though. This is a blatant security risk, so I haven't tried it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau from your comments I found this: https://brianbondy.com/blog/100/understanding-windows-at-a-deeper-level-sessions-window-stations-and-desktops
This does describe how a service can get around the issue. It also says "The user can actually set if UAC prompts should run under the current Desktop (less secure) or the Secure Desktop" and given my application this may be a viable solution.

Comment: @Martin "*The user can actually set if UAC prompts should run under the current Desktop (less secure) or the Secure Desktop*" - that is covered by the link in my 1st comment. Also, the diagram in Brian's blog regarding processes on desktops is a little misleading, since processes are tied to window stations not desktops. A single process can have multiple threads associated with different desktops within the same window station.